# Java Socket server not recieving data from client socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Hi i have a server socket that listens for requests from a client socket and my code doesnt seem to retrieve the data from its inputstream on data sent from the client socket.

below is the server socket code that listens for connections and handles the requests

```
  public void startlistener() {
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            listening = true;
            thread.start();
            Log.print(TAG, "startlistener");

        }

        public void stopListener() {
            thread.stop();
            listening = false;
            Log.print(TAG, "stopListener");
        }

    public void run() {
                while (listening) {
                    try {

                        Log.d(TAG, "inside server listener loop");
                        Socket accept = serverSocket.accept();

                        String data = getData(accept);

                        httpHandler.handleRequest(data, accept);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

    private String getData(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            Log.print(TAG, "getData");
            int c = 0;

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    //goes as far as here and then freezes/doesnt retrieve anything from the input stream
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                buffer.append((char) c);
            }
            return buffer.toString();

        }
```

**Here is my testcase**

```
private static final String HTTP_REQUEST = "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out"
        + newLine + "Cache-Control: no-cache" + newLine
        + "Connection: close" + newLine + "Content-Type: text/html";

public void testSocketConnection() {

        try {
            httpProxy = new HttpProxy(testHttpHandler);
            httpProxy.startlistener();
            testSocket = new Socket("localhost", HttpProxy.PORT);
            OutputStream outputStream = testSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream inputStream = testSocket.getInputStream();

            outputStream.write(HTTP_REQUEST.getBytes());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            httpProxy.stopListener();
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            httpProxy.stopListener();
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail(e.toString());
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client doesn't close the socket. Your server reads the socket until EOS, which will never arrive as your client doesn't close the socket.

NB don't handle client I/O in the accepting thread. Start a separate thread.

Comment: ok so as soon as i call socket.write() in the client. i should close the socket after or when appropriate?

Comment: Whenever you want the receive loop to stop. Or, change the receive loop. Have a look at the methods of DataOutputStream and DataInputStream if you want to know how to send pieces of data while keeping the socket open. Or, use Object Serialization, XML, etc.